# A question about two complemented subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

I would like to know about the differences between the following two complemented spaces.

$(1):$ If $V$ is a linear space(dim $V =\infty$ or finite), $W$ (dim $W=\infty$ or finite) is a subspace of $V$,

then there exists a subspace $W_1$ such that $V=W\oplus W_1$.

$(2):$ If $E$ is a Banach space, $G$ is a fnite-dimensional subspace of $E$,

then there exists a subspace $L$ such that $E=G\oplus L$.

What are the differences between $W_1$ and $L$?

If there is no difference between $W_1$ and $L$ , why does the second case require $G$ to be finite dimension?

Thanks!

Comment: I could be wrong, but there isn't a difference, except $L$ is now a normed space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the real point is that when you write  $V = W \oplus W_1$ in the context of a linear space, you just require $W$ and $W_1$ to be linear subspaces whose span is $V$ and whose intersection is $\{0\}$.  When you write this in the context of a Banach space, you require $W$ and $W_1$ to be closed linear subspaces.  In the context of linear spaces, all subspaces are complemented, i.e. for any linear subspace $W$ of $V$ there is always a $W_1$.  In the context of Banach spaces, not all closed linear subspaces are complemented.

Comment: @ Robert Israel   Are you saying that in the first case, the two  are just linear subspaces. In the second case both are closed subspaces. In other words, in the second case we want to find $ L$ not only complemented spaces but also a closed  subspace?

Comment: i.e. there exists  $E$ is a Banach space, $G$ (dim $G=\infty$) is a subpace, we can find a subspace $W_1$ such that  $E=G\oplus W_1$, but we cannot find a closed subspace $L$ such that $E=G\oplus L$?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, $W_1$ and  are complements of  and , respectively, meaning that they are subspaces of  and , respectively, such that  and  can be expressed as the direct sum of  and $_1$, and  and , respectively.

The main difference between $_1$ and  is that $_1$ is not necessarily a Banach space, while  is required to be a Banach space. In other words,  is a complemented subspace of a Banach space , and it must inherit the Banach space structure from . On the other hand, 1 is simply a subspace of , which may or may not be a Banach space.

Another difference is that in the first case,  is a subspace of , which may be infinite-dimensional, while in the second case,  is a finite-dimensional subspace of .